# Can't connect to SQL Server from other computers - missing any installation

Tags: c#, sql-server, database-connection, sqlconnection

I try to connect to SQL Server with my C# program - but without success.

Is it missing any setup program or run-time?

When I try from my computer - it succeeds

My sql-server version:

```
Microsoft SQL Server Standard (64-bit)  
Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP3) (KB3072779) - 11.0.6020.0 (X64)  
Oct 20 2015 15:36:27   
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.2 <X64> (Build 9200: ) (Hypervisor)
```

I try to install some Microsoft setup that I found but its still does not work.

Comment: Did you check sql server network configuration - e.g. are TCP/IP & Named pipes enabled ? Also is SQL server browser service running ?

Comment: Are you using SQL Server authentication while connecting? What is the exact error you get while connecting?

Comment: So you installed a server - but is it running? you´ve checked the port-numbers/users/..? maybe you´ve got the wrong data in your program or server-configs.

Comment: Is the firewall blocking the incoming connection perhaps?

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: thanks for the help,
the problem is not firewall or TCP/IP or server authentication. its some installation that missing on the client.